# WPF Datagrid does not fill the entire height and width when maximizing window

Tags: wpf

My DataGrid is not taking the whole space when I maximize the window in my WPF application. This is how I created the layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="265">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Date From:" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Date To:" />
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" x:Name="DateFrom" />
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" x:Name="DateTo" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Content="Send" Click="PopulateGrid"  x:Name="BtnPopulateGrid"/>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <DataGrid Width="Auto" x:Name="Grid" Height="553" 
                  Padding="10 0 0 0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10,0,-707,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and this is how it looks like on regular size:

[image]

and this is how it looks like when window is max:

[image]

What can I try next? I am new to WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding in the datagrid `ColumnWidth="*"`

It will expand all columns to avaiable space and the datagrid will fill it's parent

The second ColumnDefinition of the first grid should be `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />`

And as @Zacos said in my answers comment you have to remove Width

Comment: and remove  Width="265"

Comment: @Ibanez1408, glad it helped, check my answer cause i edited again.

Comment: This layout needs not all this grids, you can achieve this just 1 grid and 1 stacklayout. But anyway if you need to learn xaml try to learn the purpose of layouts in wpf. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Date From:" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Date To:" />
            <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" x:Name="DateFrom" />
            <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" x:Name="DateTo" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Content="Send" Click="PopulateGrid"  x:Name="BtnPopulateGrid"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" Padding="10 0 0 0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Firstly if you wanna make your datagrid fill a container automatically, you need to use Grid, not StackPanel also your datagrid sizes need to be set auto.

Edit:
As @Erjon said : You don't have to use a container when you have a single DataGrid.But if you have more components with your DataGrid, Grid will be a better container choice instead of StackPanel.

Your main GridDefination sizes were set as Auto, that was wrong.You need to work with "*" if you want a resposive design.Auto means that "Set this control's size with its children".

[image]

Comment: Why do you need another grid to put the DataGrid?

Comment: Thank you for that lesson. It is really helpful. Only if I use the <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>, when I maximize, the datagrid gets centered but does not fill the whole height.

Comment: @Erjon He used a StackPanel for it.I just replaced as Grid if he wants a future plan he can use it in proper way.Please  check your downvote.

Comment: I understand but in this case he has just only the datagrid inside your grid. He is not inserting another control that should stay in front of the datagrid. I think that your example is valid like for example he want's to show a progressbar and needs it to be shown in the middle of the datagrid.

Comment: I just tried to tell that StackPanel is not a good way for responsive designing. Yeah He could put his DataGrid alone. However i think i didn't deserve that. Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm trying to change the downvote, but it is saying that i cant change that unless your answer is edited. Please do it and i will change the downvote.

Comment: @BulutaySaraç i feelt sorry yesterday and i checked your answers and they really helped me, i voted them to, you have noticed i guess.

Comment: Yes, i have noticed. If you found my answers useful it is a very good condition for me. Thank you very much again.